# How to line up a css ::before pseudo element like a grid

Tags: html, css

Is there a way, using css only, to line up a multiline element (and anchor in my example) so that the "before" bit and the "anchor" bit appear side by side as though in a grid.

I.e.

```
>   i am a test link
    which goes over
    multiple lines
```

As opposed to the result of this (which will hopefully show it wrapping underneath the before content).

```css
a::before {
  content: ">";
  padding-right: 20px;
}

div {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <a href="#">i am a test link which goes over multiple lines</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`display:table/table-cell` works nicely.

```css
a::before {
  content: ">";
  padding-right: 20px;
}
div {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

/* relevant stuff */
a {
  display: table;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a::before {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">i am a test link which goes over multiple lines</a>
</div>
```

Or as inspired by Nenad Vracar's original answer, Flexbox

```css
a::before {
  content: ">";
  padding-right: 20px;
}
div {
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 1em;
}

/* relevant stuff */
a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">i am a test link which goes over multiple lines</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant - thanks.  I had tried table-cell, but omitted to put put display table on the parent.  Schoolboy error!

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Flexbox** like this and you can also vertically align items

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/312/)**

```
div {
  width: 150px;
}

a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

a:before {
  content: ">";
  margin: 5px;
}
```

---

```
<div>
   <a href="#">i am a test link which goes over multiple lines</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to add the `padding-left` value to the parent anchor element, followed by `display: inline-block`/`position: relative`. Then absolutely position the pseudo element relative to the parent:

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
a::before {
  content: ">";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

div {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <a href="#">i am a test link which goes over multiple lines</a>
</div>
```